# SQL-based query to project from 4326 to 3857?

Tags: sql

While most SQL databases have in-built projection tools (usually st_transform), BigQuery does not. I'm looking for a SQL query that takes decimal degrees in 4326 and projects them into the meter-based 3857. I have searched SO and the internet, and similar questions usually pertain to people having issues using tools like GDAL, rather than the pure expression itself, which is what I'm looking for. Can anyone share one?

Comment: What languages can you use to extend "BigQuery"? - you aren't going to get a pure SQL expression to do the reprojection

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on that, to help me understand? What is it that SQL can't handle natively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the *BigQuery* dialect (if any?), but this is standard SQL:

```
SELECT 6378137.0 * <lon> * ACOS(-1)/180.0 AS x,
       6378137.0 * LN( TAN( (ACOS(-1) * 0.25) + (0.5 * <lat> * ACOS(-1) / 180.0) ) ) AS y
;
```

with

- `6378137.0 = <radius_of_auxiliary_sphere>`
- `ACOS(-1) = PI`
- `<lonlat_in_degree> * PI/180.0 = <lonlat_in_radians>`

---

However, in order to comply with the [projection bounds](https://epsg.io/3857), and to avoid going *infinity* at the poles, you have to clip the results to `+/-20026376.39 | +/-20048966.10`, e.g. with

```
SELECT LEAST(GREATEST(x, -20026376.39), 20026376.39) AS x,
       LEAST(GREATEST(y, -20048966.10), 20048966.10) AS y
FROM   (
  SELECT 6378137.0 * <lon> * ACOS(-1)/180.0 AS x,
         6378137.0 * LN( TAN( (ACOS(-1) * 0.25) + (0.5 * <lat> * ACOS(-1) / 180.0) ) ) AS y
  -- FROM   <exp>
) AS q
```

or drop outliers e.g. in a `WHERE` filter.

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you for the great answer!